Why doesn't VSCode recognize the Hands class from the mediapipe library despite correct installation?
I am working on an AI Python project in VSCode and using the mediapipe library (version 0.10.11). While the library is correctly installed in my virtual environment (aivmp) and works when I run the code, VSCode does not recognize the Hands class or other components from mediapipe.solutions.hands. Hovering over Hands only shows (function) Hands: Any without any class details or documentation.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
a) Installed mediapipe: I installed mediapipe in my virtual environment using:
pip install mediapipe

The installation works fine, and pip show mediapipe confirms the correct version and path in the environment.
b) Python Environment in VSCode:
I selected the correct Python interpreter in VSCode:
Python 3.8.10 ('aivmp') .\aivmp\Scripts\python.exe

The virtual environment is active in the integrated terminal.
c) Working Code: This simple code runs without errors:

import mediapipe as mp
print(mp.__version__)

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()

d) What works:

Hovering over import mediapipe as mp shows the library's metadata and version.
The library openCV2 functions correctly when running the script.

e) The problem:

Hovering over Hands or similar classes/functions doesn’t show detailed documentation or type information.
VSCode doesn’t seem to provide proper IntelliSense or autocomplete for the mediapipe library.

Is this an issue with mediapipe type hints or how VSCode handles certain dynamically imported libraries? How can I make VSCode recognize the Hands class and provide proper IntelliSense/autocomplete for mediapipe?
Any insights would be appreciated! Greetings!
